# Most clear, Pythonic, reliable, and fastest way to check if a string contains words from a list of lists

Tags: python

I am looking for the most clear, Pythonic, and fastest way to check if a string contains words from a list of lists

This is what I came up so far

```
introStrings = ['introduction:' , 'case:' , 'introduction' , 'case' ]
backgroundStrins = ['literature:' , 'background:',  'Related:' , 'literature' , 'background',  'related' ]
methodStrings = [ 'methods:' , 'method:', 'techniques:', 'methodology:' , 'methods' , 'method', 'techniques', 'methodology' ]
resultStrings = [ 'results:', 'result:', 'experimental:', 'experiments:', 'experiment:', 'results', 'result', 'experimental', 'experiments', 'experiment']
discussioStrings = [ 'discussion:' , 'Limitations:'  , 'discussion' , 'limitations']
conclusionStrings = ['conclusion:' , 'conclusions:', 'concluding:' , 'conclusion' , 'conclusions', 'concluding' ]

allStrings = [ introStrings, backgroundStrins, methodStrings, resultStrings, discussioStrings, conclusionStrings ]

testtt = 'this may thod be in techniques ever material and methods'

for item in allStrings:
    for word in testtt.split():
        if word in item:
            print('yes')
            break
```

This code pretty looks for all combinations. It's a nested for loop. It it's not quite clear to figure out on first glance.

I am wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: Why do you print `item`?

Comment: I wanted to see if it's in the list. It's more clear for the problem statement if I just printed 'yes' so I edited this change into my original question.

Comment: Will your `testtt` contain colons `:` ?

Comment: sometimes yes it will

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I can get is by use of `chain` and `any`:

```
resultStrings = [
    "results:",
    "result:",
    "experimental:",
    "experiments:",
    "experiment:",
    "results",
    "result",
    "experimental",
    "experiments",
    "experiment",
]
conclusionStrings = [
    "conclusion:",
    "conclusions:",
    "concluding:",
    "conclusion",
    "conclusions",
    "concluding",
]

allStrings = [resultStrings, conclusionStrings]
testtt = "this may thod be in techniques ever material and methods"

from itertools import chain
string_set = set(chain(*allStrings))
any(i in string_set for i in testtt.split())
```

Though `set` need some space, it can improve efficiency. Thanks **Peter Wood.**

Comment: @PeterWood  Times of chain will be called depends on. sorry to delete my first respond.

Comment: There were no intermediate lists to begin with in the original question

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh Added.

Comment: `chain` will be called for every word in `testtt`, but the result will be the same every time. This is inefficient. It also performs a linear search of the chained values. Better to build a `set` once.

Answer (score 3):

It would be more Pythonic to use `any()` with a chained list comprehension:

```
print any(word in sublist for word in testtt.split() for sublist in allStrings)
```

However this will just return true/false; it won't identify which word was found in which sublist.  You can print the specific matches with this list comprehension:

```
print [(word,sublist) for word in testtt.split() for sublist in allStrings if word in sublist]
```

Your code is a bit wasteful by calculating `testtt.split()` more than once.

Comment: Actually, I think the right syntax would be `[word for sublist in allStrings for word in sublist]`

Comment: Both have the same time-complexity, but one might be better over the other depending on how the `testtt` string looks like

Answer (score 2):

> I am looking for the most clear, Pythonic, and fastest way to check if a string contains words from a list of lists

First, I'd flatten the lists

```
all_strings = [*intro, *back, *methods, ...] # You get the idea
```

(Alternatively, using a nested list comprehension)

```
all_strings = [word for list in [intro, back, ...] for word in list] # if you're into that
```

Next, split the string:

```
string_words = a_string.split()
```

Finally, just look up words:

```
found = [w for w in string_words if w in all_strings]
```

That's quite pythonic, not very sure about speed or reliability

Comment: Linear search is not fast.

Comment: I agree, a hashmap could've been better

Answer (score 1):

Using itertools

```
import itertools
merged = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(allStrings))
[print(x) for x in testtt.split() if x in merged]
```

Comment: Why make `merged` a list, when a `set` would be more efficient for searching?